# Include binary data file into APK file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin, assets

I have a problem to include a binary file into the APK file.

The openwig library includes a binary data file (stdlib.lbc) which are loaded from the library code.

```
InputStream stdlib = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cz/matejcik/openwig/stdlib.lbc");
```

In the past I build the project - without any handmade modifications - with Eclipse and everything was okay. The binary file was loaded and an InputStream object was returned. The APK file includes under the folder cz\matejcik\openwig the file stdlib.lbc. Everything was okay.

Now I try to build the project with Android Studio 1.3.2 and the APK file doesn't include the APK file anymore. Of cource the loading code returns null.

The file stdlib.lbc is located in the project under \app\OpenWIGLibrary\src\matejcik\openwig. The file is shown in the project tree in Android Studio, too.

I make some tries to include the stdlib.lbc via the gradle configuration but I'm not successful, because I have never edit gradle configurations before. Is the gradle configuration the right way? How to include a binary file into the APK file via Android Studio?

By the way, I don't want to move the stdlib.lbc into the assets folder, because I want to modify the code from the openwig library.

Thank you for help
AndroidNovize42

Answer (score 0):

You should have your resources in the std file for them: `src/main/resources`. If you want them to appear in a given package, just go creating folders following your package structure and leave them in there.

By default, with no gradle explicit config, only java is taken from the src folder, compiled and then .class files copied to the destination package by maven/gradle.

Other way could be adding your files to the assets folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not the answer which I expected ;-). I move the stdlib.lbc file into the assets folder and change the location path. And it works. But there are two point why I'm not so happy with this solution: First I have to move a file and second have to change code from and third-part library.